# Implementation of centered binomial distribution in Kyber Key Encapsulation Mechanism?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, kyber

In the implementation of centered binomial distribution of **crystals-kyber**, the authors load 24-bits of buffer to a 32 bit integer and then they and the answer with **0x00249249**. The complete operations are below:

1. t = load24_littleendian(buf+3*i)
2. d = t & 0x00249249
3. d += (t>>1) & 0x00249249
4. d += (t>>2) & 0x00249249

Can someone please explain what is actually happening here because in documentation this whole procedure is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If passed uniformly random 24-bit values, this code generates 8 independent, bit-packed $\mathcal B(3,0.5)$ samples. The samples are encoded in the 24 least significant bits of $d$ with each sample represented by one of the tri-bits 000, 001, 010 or 011 according to whether they are 0, 1, 2 or 3.

To see this note that `0x249249` in binary is `1001001001001001001001` and thus masks off every third bit. If the bits of `t` can be treated as i.i.d. Bernoulli variables with $p=1/2$ (i.e. as uniform independent bits), the sum of any three bit positions of `t` will give a $\mathcal B(3,0.5)$ sample. The code divides `t` into three bit chunks and counts the number of bits in each chunk by initialising (in a bit parallel manner) to the value of the least significant bit in each chunk; adding one (in bit-parallel) if the next least significant bit in each chunk is set and finally adding one (in bit-parallel) if the third bit in each chunk is set.

An example might help here. Suppose we have `t=011100101011000110111110` as input. To form binomial samples by hand we would divide this into chunks of three: `011 100 101 011 000 110 111 110`, then count the bits in each chunk `2 1 2 2 0 2 3 2`, then pack these answers as `010 001 010 010 000 010 011 010`. The code achieves the same output by first masking off every third bit of `t` to initialise `d=001000001001000000001000`, it then adds on to this the value of the bits in every position that is 1 mod 3 by shifting `t` and masking: `01000000001000001001001` so that after adding (with carries) we have `d=010000001010000001010001`. Our next summand is the value of the bits in positions 2 mod 3 which we create by shifting `t` by 2 and masking: `0001001000000001001001` so that after adding (with carries) we have `d=010001010010000010011010` as required. Note that the carries from each chunk never overflow into the next chunk up.